# Why is -i++ and -(i++) different ? Why is the result as follows?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Order of evaluation of arguments using std::cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718508/order-of-evaluation-of-arguments-using-stdcout)

**I have known it now!This is responsible for *'cout'***
The all code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int i = 3;
   cout <<-i++<<endl<<i<<endl<<-(i++)<<endl<<i<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I use VC++6.0 to compile,output is : `-4 4 -3 3`
But I use g++ to compile,output is : `-4 5 -3 5`
Why? I think they should be the same : `-4 4 -4 4`

PS:I try it：

```
int main()
{
   int i = 3;
   cout <<-i++<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

And

```
int main()
{
   int i = 3;
   cout <<-（i++）<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I compile they one by one,the result is the same:-3 3
Thinks to all answers,I maybe have a mistake of testing -i++ and -(i++) somehow

Comment: could you reformat so we can see the full code.

Comment: It comes down to the order of evaluation. Have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181211/prefix-postfix-increment-operators

Comment: I am a greenhand of C++,I haven't learned class

Comment: @GrinV A useful [like to you answer](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#evaluation-order)

Comment: Thinks to your link,it is so detail that I must spend long time reading ,because I am Chinese,my English is poor

Comment: The real problem of your code is that the order of evaluation of each expression is unspecified, so it may print different stuff depending on the mood of the compiler; read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718508/order-of-evaluation-of-arguments-using-stdcout)

Comment: There is no way that the code you have shown can result in either output.  Cut and paste the code you're actually running.

Comment: @GrinV: While each of your output statements depends on the order of evaluation, the actual results you reported are unrealistic. The code you posted cannot possibly produce the output you posted. Post the exact code that you ran and the exact output that it printed.

Comment: So,how can I master i++,I so confuse

Answer (score 6):

As it stands right now, your code has undefined behavior. You're both using the value of `i` and modifying `i` without an intervening sequence point<sup>1</sup>. This gives undefined behavior.

The difference in results between the two lines does *not* stem from the use of parentheses -- it stems purely from the fact that the `++` in the first line modifies the value of `i`, so when you reach the second line, its value has been incremented.

To summarize, since you have undefined behavior, *any* output is perfectly reasonable and allowed, but the `-4 4 -3 3` is quite reasonable and understandable.

---

1. As of C++ 11, the standard no longer uses the phrase "sequence point", but uses phrasing like "sequenced before" or "sequenced after" to describe the same basic intent. A *few* things ended up getting defined behavior from this change, but not many (and, specifically, not this code).

Comment: In a word,the output -4 4 -3 3 is not the right result,is the any output depend the compiler mood?

Comment: @GrinV: Correct -- there is not really any one correct result. At least officially, any result you get is equally correct.

Comment: I have a mistake of testing -(i++) and -i++ somehow

Answer (score 1):

The two lines are the same

Try

```
int i = 3;
cout << - i++  << endl << i << endl;
i=3
cout << -(i++) << endl << i << endl;
```

The operator precedence for any operator is found here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

And, *postfix ++* (the one you use) has higher precedence than *Unary plus and minus*.

On the other hand, you should read this Q and A:

[Why is a = i + i++ undefined and not unspecified behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572618/why-is-a-i-i-undefined-and-not-unspecified-behaviour)

Your examples are actually identical to this:

```
(
  (
    (
      cout.operator<<(-(i++))
    ).operator<<(endl)
  ).operator<<(i)
).operator<<(endl);
```

In essence, modifying a variable and using it in the same expression is often *undefined behaviour*: the program is allowed to do *anything*.

Comment: Interestingly, since the order of evaluation is unspecified, despite being the same the two lines may produce different output.

Comment: Is that true?  Do the *overloaded* `<<` and `>>` operators not introduce a sequence point?

Comment: Thinks,I have to sleep now,I will read it later

Comment: Yes,you are right  ,think you

Comment: @MatteoItalia, I think "Hello World" is an allowed output also...

Comment: @JohanLundberg: I'm not entirely sure, IIRC the order of evaluation is simply *unspecified*, so it's not *undefined behavior* (where even nuclear war would be an allowed output).

Comment: @JohanLundberg: ok, I checked; §1.9 ¶15 says «If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to [...] a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined», so you are right, it's UB.